# Social Media connect

Tags: twitter, linkedin-api, twitter-oauth

I am want to add social media connect to my web app which includes twitter, Facebook and Linkedin.

I want to include twitter connect to my site. But I am not getting how to do it. I have implemented the fb connect to my app.

I am also look for good linkedin connect to my site how do I include it. Please let me know

Comment: I am using servlets at the back end and jquery and javascript at the front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the simplest ways to integrate Twitter with your website is by using [@anywhere](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere).  Take a look at the [documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere/begin) and see if it seems to be a good fit for your application.